# jQuery mobile Panel header and footer height difference

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, Visiting the demo of the [Panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-fixed/) shows the below image on the left, but when I copy the code and run it in the same browser I get the below image on the right.
Please notice the  **height difference of the header and footer**.

I tried to include my.css and reset the html&body for no avail.  I could not think of any other info to include here.

How can this be fixed?  Thanks

[image]

As requested, here is the CSS from google chrome element inspection panel:

```css
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 30%;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
user agent stylesheeth1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from header.ui-header.ui-bar-inherit.ui-header-fixed.slidedown
.ui-bar-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-bar-a .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-body-a .ui-bar-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-bar-inherit {
    background-color: #e9e9e9 /*{a-bar-background-color}*/;
    border-color: #ddd /*{a-bar-border}*/;
    color: #333 /*{a-bar-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bar-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-radius}*/ #eee /*{a-bar-shadow-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from div.ui-page.ui-page-theme-a.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-active
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9 /*{a-page-background-color}*/;
    border-color: #bbb /*{a-page-border}*/;
    color: #333 /*{a-page-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-page-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-page-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-page-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-page-shadow-color}*/;
}
Inherited from body.ui-mobile-viewport.ui-overlay-a
.ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a, .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
    background-color: #f9f9f9 /*{a-page-background-color}*/;
    border-color: #bbb /*{a-page-border}*/;
    color: #333 /*{a-page-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-page-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-page-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-page-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-page-shadow-color}*/;
}
body, input, select, textarea, button, .ui-btn {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-family: sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
}
Inherited from html.ui-mobile
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Here is the whole file which is producing the error, please adjust your path for the "public" libraries in the head tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>RRR</title>
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css"/> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos" id="panel-fixed-page1" data-title="Panel fixed positioning" data-url="panel-fixed-page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Fixed header</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
        <h1>Panel fixed positioning</h1>
        <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the push display mode. The right panel opens as overlay. For both panels we set <code>data-position-fixed="true"</code>. We also set position fixed for the header and footer on this page.</p>
        <p>The left panel contains a long menu to demonstrate that the framework will check the panel contents height and unfixes the panel so its content can be scrolled. In the right panel there is a short form that shows the fixed positioning.</p>
        <div data-demo-html="#panel-fixed-page1"></div><!--/demo-html -->
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="../" data-rel="back" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Back</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>We made the page a bit longer because you only see the panel fixed positioning if you can scroll the page :-)</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Fixed footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Form elements</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Grids</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Listviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Loader overlay</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Navbar, persistent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Popup</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Radio buttons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Select</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Slider, single</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">New</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Text inputs & textarea</a></li>
                <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Transitions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" id="add-form">
        <form class="userform">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <label for="name">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini">Save</a></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
</div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header and footer title css is as follows

```
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 30%;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: 0!important;
}
```

padding is `padding: .7em 0;`

anything greater like `padding: 2em 0;`

will get you this

[image]

so check your css and make sure padding is `padding: .7em 0;`

**UPDATE**

I don't see the css for `.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title` in your Q

make sure your mouse pointer is directly on the headers title text not the header itself. you should see something like this, not that bunch of other css code you added in your question. do you see that, or is it missing?

[image]

as a test add the following at the end of the head in your document to see if it helps

```
<HEAD>
...
...
...
<style>
    .ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {

        padding: .7em 0 !important;

    }
</style>

<HEAD>
```

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation. I do not have any css of my own on this document, neither external nor in the file.

Comment: @Fred J.  --  using crhome browser right click on the title text in the header and choose inspect. under Elements copy and paste the css code from the right side of the screen in your Question  as you see in my answer. if you don't use chrome then check the net on how to inspect an element for that browser

Comment: OK. please see as I included the css info in my question, I wrote this comments to show the red tag on your end because I am not sure if SO informs you when I edit the question, It would be good to know that :)

Comment: Please see update in my question as you requested. Also, adding the styling in the head as you suggested did not fix the problem or changed anything, I test it on both the AptanaStudio Show Preview and on the browsers (Chrome, FireFox, Safari)

Comment: @Fred J -- the css look ok. do you have a webserver to post me a link to view on my browser, or can you zip your test project and post it to download. i can then tell you for sure what the issue is

Comment: @Fred J -- actually even better use jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ and add all the code including the css -- JQM cdn here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-mobile  -- down the bottom you find jqm.min.css and js -- you also need the Jquery cdn (choose the right version from the drop down menu)  -- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Comment: I posted the whole file in question. please adjust the path for the public libraries included in the head tag. Thank you for taking the time to look into this.:)

Comment: @Fred J   -- well i copied your code and used the cdn for the css and  js files --  looks fine to me -- https://jsfiddle.net/m96pfnp1/  -- add cdn  links that i have in the fiddle for those files in your project and retest

Comment: Thank you. I found that copying your "good" file into my project does not duplicate the problem even when I replace the libraries back to my local ones. So I will use that "good" file. It must be left over white space somewhere in the bod.